# PL/SQL Trigger exercise

Tags: plsql, triggers

I have this question that I can see what it's asking but just can't wrap my head around how to write it specifically:

When a new tuple is inserted into the sales order detail, your trigger should insert a corresponding raw material tuple in the Inventory Report table for the Report date (i.e., beginning inventory level, consumption quantity, same-day order quantity, next-day order quantity)

Assumptions I gathered from the notes:

itemID = itemID from RAWMATERIALS table

reportDate = dueDate from SALESORDERS table

begInv = inventoryLevels from RAWMATERIALS table

consumpQty = itemID from FINISHEDGOODS * rmQuantity (raw material required to make each finished good) from FINISHED GOODS

orderNextDay = If consumpQty <= begInv then orderNextDay = consumpQty
                        orderSameDay = 0

orderSameDay = If consumpQty > begInv then  orderNextDay = begInv
                        orderSameDay = consumpQty - begInv

I thought the trigger might go something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER inv_report
BEFORE INSERT
ON SALESORDERDETAIL
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE  
item_id RAWMATERIALS.ITEMID%TYPE
reportDate SALESORDERS.DUEDATE%TYPE
begInv RAWMATERIALS.INVENTORYLEVEL%TYPE
```

And then I understand we would probably need to INSERT into INVENTORYREPORT table (which currently has no data in it) and maybe do an IF ELSEIF statement to satisfy the orderNextDay and orderSameDay columns but i'm still not familiar enough with PL/SQL to know exactly how to tackle this.

Can anyone help me out with this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to find some time to write up some code for you on this, but my first recommendation is to NOT do this in a trigger. Instead, create a procedure "insert_so_detail" that inserts into the the SALESORDERDETAIL and then does the related insert into INVENTORYREPORT.

That procedure is then always called to insert into the S-O-D table. Executing DML inside triggers is a tricky thing to do because the database might decide it needs to restart the DML and then possibly do another insert into the I-R table. Check out this [AskTOM thread](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2599480800346313755#2600827300346401245) for more details.

You are always better off putting your DML into PL/SQL package APIs, then only allow DML on the table *through* the API (grant execute on the package, do NOT grant insert or update or delete on the table directly to a user).

Comment: Ok that would be great thanks!  It was an exercise that we have to solve with a trigger unfortunately.  I appreciate the help with this

Comment: I have been playing with it a little more and have:  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigSales
AFTER INSERT 
ON SALESORDERDETAIL
FOR EACH ROW
 
    `DECLARE
    temp_ItemID rawmaterials.itemid%type;
    reportDate salesorders.duedate%type;
    begInvLevel rawmaterials.inventorylevel%type;
    temp_rmquantity finishedgoods.rmquantity%type;
    
    
    BEGIN
    Insert into INVENTORYREPORT      (ITEMID,REPORTDATE,BEGINNINGINVENTORYLEVEL,CONSUM    PTIONQUANTITY,ORDERNEXTDAY,ORDERSAMEDAY)    '', '', '');`

Comment: `/*:new.consumptionquantity := temp_rmquantity * temp_ItemID;
    IF consumptionquantity <= begInvLevel
    THEN orderNextDay := consumptionquantity;
    ELSE IF consumptionquantity > begInvLevel
    THEN orderNextDay := begInvLevel;
    ELSE  orderSameDay := consumptionquantity - begInvLevel;
    END IF;*/
    
END;
/`

Comment: Can anyone give me some insight into this?  I’m trying to finish this for a group project that I said I’d have ready today and I still can’t quite figure it out. Thanks a ton!